# SSH still asks password after copying the public key to Linux server from Windows

Tags: ssh, server, public-key-encryption, openssh

Here is the log when ssh

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\x/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\x/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for server-x
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to server-x [10.81.24.118] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\x/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\x/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.7
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to server-x:22 as 'x'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\x/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: xxxxxxx
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\x/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host server-x is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\x/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\x/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:YIkF8FEzeVmk5i/FYJY0Z1IWYtXhRyjHnKOp9++Mmn4 explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,keyboard-interactive,hostbased
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
```

Why on the debug information, it does not have the pubkey option
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,keyboard-interactive,hostbased

I tried to update the ssh file
.ssh/config

Host server-x
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

On the server side, the pub key is saved in authorized_keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why on the debug information, it does not have the pubkey option debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,keyboard-interactive,hostbased

Public key authentication isn't currently enabled on that host, otherwise you'd see `publickey` in that list. Someone with root access on that server will need to update `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, making sure `PubkeyAuthentication` is set to `yes` (and not commented out), and then restart the SSHD daemon.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked once after I update sshd_config and restart the daemon. But when I tried to log in again, it started to require password and when I checked the sshd_config PubkeyAuthentication is set to no again. Is there anyway to fix PubkeyAuthentication to be yes?

Comment: This solution did not work. In fact on one serve this option is not enabled and I can still connect from the same client,

Comment: @KenIngram can you elaborate?

Comment: I set up the public key for two different servers. On one server I can log in  without the password. On the one I configured today, it keeps asking for password. Same client. Do I need to use a different key on each server?

Comment: You should be able to use the same key on multiple servers. Does `ssh -v` on the second server show that pubkey is an option for authentication? Have you added the key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the second server?

Comment: I followed the same procedure on both servers. The key was added to the newer server.